# What is the meaning of ように here?

Tags: translation, meaning

Can someone tell me what ように means in this phrase?

> あの人にそんな秘密があるようには全く見えないがな。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ように見える

can often be translated as "looks like". In your case,

> あの人にそんな秘密があるようには全く見えないがな
>   He really didn't look like somebody, who was keeping such a secret.

This よう would be [this one](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=18849000), written 様 and meaning amongst others "look, appearance".

There are [lots of questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86) about よう（に）. Reading some of them might be helpful as well.